# Save reversal relationship item in database using one POST - Django

Tags: python, django

I want a viewset that handles a post request that creates some nested objects using the post data.

I have these models, serializers, and views:

**Models:**

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    from portfolio.models import Portfolio

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='exchange_connections', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolios = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio)

class ConnectionSettings(models.Model):
    exchange_connection = models.OneToOneField(Connection, to_field='id', primary_key=True,
                                               related_name='settings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    import_past_transactions = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)


class ConnectionCredentials(models.Model):
    exchange_connection = models.OneToOneField(Connection, to_field='id', primary_key=True,
                                               related_name='credentials', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    key = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    passphrase = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Serializers:**

```
 class ConnectionCredentialsSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ConnectionCredentials
        fields = '__all__'


class ConnectionSettingsSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ConnectionSettings
        fields = '__all__'


class ConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credentials = ConnectionCredentialsSerializer()
    settings = ConnectionSettingsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Connection
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        credentials = validated_data.pop('credentials')
        settings = validated_data.pop('settings')

        connection = Connection.objects.create(**validated_data)
        ConnectionCredentials.objects.create(exchange_connection=connection, **credentials)
        ConnectionSettings.objects.create(exchange_connection=connection, **settings)

        return connection
```

**Views:**

```
 class ConnectionViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ConnectionSerializer
    queryset = exchange_models.Connection.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, core_permissions.IsMineOnly)

    def list(self):
        return HttpResponse(self.request.user.exchange_connections_set)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(exchange_models.Connection.objects.get(id=pk)).data
        return HttpResponse(serialized_data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create(serializer.data)
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status': 'connection created.'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**URLs:**

```
# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'connections', views.ConnectionViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**POST Request:**

[image: postman post request]

When I send the post request, the portfolios and the user already exist. So I should only give primary keys to these rows in my request.
But I need to create new rows for Settings and Credentials for which I should pass data in the request.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default nested serializers are `read-only`. You will have to customize the create method to make it writable.

```
class ConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    portfolios = PortfolioSerializer(many=True)
    credentials = ConnectionCredentialsSerializer(many=False)
    settings = ConnectionSettings(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Connection
        exclude = ('user',)
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'last_updated')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        portfolios = validated_data.pop('portfolios')
        credentials = validated_data.pop('credentials')
        settings = validated_data.pop('settings')
        connection = Connection.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
        for portfolio in portfolios:
            Portfolio.objects.create(exchange_connection=connection, **portfolio)
    
        for credential in credentials:
            ConnectionCredentials.objects.create(exchange_connection=connection, **credentials)
    
        for setting in settings:
            ConnectionSettings.objects.create(exchange_connection=connection, **settings)
    
        return connection
```

Provided that following are the model names relative to serializers.

```
PortfolioSerializer -> Portfolio, 

ConnectionCredentialsSerializer -> ConnectionCredentials
```

Comment: Should I remove `portfolios = PortfolioSerializer(many=True)
    credentials = ConnectionCredentialsSerializer(many=False)
    settings = ConnectionSettings(many=False)` in my serializer ?

Comment: also, it says: `'ConnectionSerializer' object has no attribute 'pop'`

Comment: You don't have to remove nested serializers.

Comment: You need to put above `create` function in `ConnectionSerializer`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: now it says I don't send the fields even if I do: `{
    "credentials": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "settings": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}`

Comment: I updated my current `ViewSet` in my question.

Comment: Right! Can you add POST request body in your question?

Comment: Question updated, I changed some text to be more clear! 
I use Postman to send requests.

Comment: In fact, I was sending data in form-data but I should send it in raw. Now it works!